# Centering my drop-up menu

Tags: html, css, centering

I had a question fairly similar to this that I had asked last week, but I have ran into another problem. I've made a fiddle for you guys! Fingers crossed this is an easy fix!

Here is the link to the relevant question from last week:

[Footer's nav submenu won't stay open after I mouse out unless I mouse over quickly and hover far left/right of my ul open submenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51758002/footers-nav-submenu-wont-stay-open-after-i-mouse-out-unless-i-mouse-over-quick)

I have now gotten rid of the majority of the percentages in my code, and it has created some centering problems.

My drop-up menu (#footer-nav ul ul) is no longer centered in the page and I can't seem to get it centered! Before I removed most of the percentages in the code, setting #info > ul 's margin-left to calc(-50% + 18.67px) worked, but that is no longer working!

Any and all help would be so greatly appreciated! You guys are life savers!!!

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c74jsgub/14/

EDIT: I'm new to coding, so if you guys notice anything in the code that could be better etc, let me know! :)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <footer id="footer">
         <div id="footer-nav">
            <ul>
               <li id="info">
                  INFO
                  <ul>
                     <li id="twitter">
                        <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">TWITTER</a>
                     </li>
                     <li id="instagram">
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">INSTAGRAM</a>
                     </li>
                     <li id="email">
                        <a href="mailto:mail@mail.com">EMAIL</a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 11;
}

#footer-nav {
  width: 100%;
}

#info {
  display: inline-block;
}

#footer-nav ul {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

#footer-nav ul ul {
  width: 300px;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: none;
}

#footer-nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto 0;
}

#twitter {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: white;
}

#twitter:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#email {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: white;
}

#email:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#instagram {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: white;
}

#instagram:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#info>ul {
  margin-left: calc(-50% + 15px);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is one of [**specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

**[My old rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51758064/2341603)** of `margin-left: calc(-50% + 15px)` is still getting applied to `#info > ul`, but unfortunately the selector `#footer-nav ul li:hover>ul` has more specificity. This selector has the rule `margin: 0 auto`, which overwrites the `calc()` rule.

First you will need to use a more specific selector, like `#footer-nav ul #info:hover>ul`.

In addition to this, you'll also want to slightly adjust the `margin-left`. This time, you want need `calc()`, and can get by with just `margin-left: -132px`.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 11;
}

#footer-nav {
  width: 100%;
}

#info {
  display: inline-block;
}

#footer-nav ul {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

#footer-nav ul ul {
  width: 300px;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: none;
}

#footer-nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto 0;
}

#twitter {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: white;
}

#twitter:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#email {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: white;
}

#email:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#instagram {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: white;
}

#instagram:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#footer-nav ul #info:hover>ul {
  margin-left: -132px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <footer id="footer">
    <div id="footer-nav">
      <ul>
        <li id="info">INFO
          <ul>
            <li id="twitter">
              <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">TWITTER</a>
            </li>
            <li id="instagram">
              <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">INSTAGRAM</a>
            </li>
            <li id="email">
              <a href="mailto:mail@mail.com">EMAIL</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see! Thank you so much Simon! I will be adding all of that to my code right now! :)

Comment: The calculation still isn't quite right to work responsively, but I'm glad this helped you. I'll have a play around and see if I can work out the exact math you need to work for all screen widths.

Comment: Updated - I was getting myself confused. You no longer need `calc()` due to the positoning, and can get by with just subtracting the width of the popout menu plus the borders. In this case, you're looking for `margin-left: -132px`. The specificity issue is still one you'll want to resolve, but I've updated my answer to correct this. Good luck with the site :)

Comment: Thank you so much man! The site is coming together, but without your help there is no way I could get it to work like I need it to work. May I ask how you found the "-132px"? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it centered by tweaking your margin and positioning for the `#footer-nav ul ul`. Remember that you need horizontal margins to be `auto` rather than `0` for centering.

```
#footer-nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto; /* not auto 0 */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c74jsgub/41/

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you so much Jack! Entered the code into Dreamweaver and it was fixed right away! :) Thanks again and have a great rest of your day!!